# Node.js establish connection to remote mysql server using tunnel-ssh

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssh

I am using the `tunnel-ssh` module to establish connection to the remote `mysql` database using node.js. The documentation is poor and I am not able to establish a connection. Here is the code snippet:

```
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh')
var server = tunnel.tunnel(config.sshData, function(err, result) {console.log('connected'});
```

Here is my sshData object.

```
config.sshData = {host : 'serverxyz.web-hosting.com', username : 'xyz', password : 'xyz',
srcPort: 3307, dstPort : 21098}
```

The `dstPort` is `21098` as suggested by the [namecheap documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server).

However I am getting timeout error and whenever I add this snippet:

```
server.on('error', function(err) {});
```

I get the error `server.on is not a function`. The remote connection is working fine on `putty` and `SQLyog`. Any procedure on how to establish successful connection would be of great help. Thanks!

**Update**

Got the database working by using the correct ports specified and by directly using `ssh2` module with the code example given [here](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/351)

Comment: I think that dstPort is the port your DB is available on. So if the DB is running on localhost:3307 then use `dstPort: 3307`

Comment: I've used the correct port number as specified by the answer, still getting  timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding with the namecheap documentation. 21098 is the *ssh* port, not the port the database is listening on. In order to use a non-standard ssh port, you will need to explicitly specify the `port` value like:

```
config.sshData = {
  host: 'serverxyz.web-hosting.com',
  port: 21098,
  username: 'xyz',
  password: 'xyz',
  dstPort: 3306
};
```

Then you should be able to connect to `localhost:3306` to access your remote database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting a timeout error even if use the correct port as specified. `events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at null._onTimeout (..\node_modules\tunnel-ssh\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:569:19)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)`

Comment: I'm able to connect to the remote host and execute `uptime` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2). Any ideas on how to proceed would be of great help!

Comment: I got the db working from your code given at (https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/351)